# MYSQL - How to display the row and skip duplicated rows when previous row's having a same column's value?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I display the first row of record and skip the rest of duplicated rows which have a same column value matching with the first column value?

For example, I wish skip id: 6, 7, 8 because the value of id: 6, 7, 8 is repeated after the value in id: 4 and continue display for id: 10, 12 because the previous value of id: 10, 12 not repeated.

[image]

Comment: Don't use a link to an image for your data. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't understand why id 10 and 12 are selected ? They are repeated right ?

Comment: Why 9, 10, 11, 12? The values are available earlier.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I agree with you Sebastian, I don't understand ... Please give us more information else we can't help you

Comment: @Gosfly - I'm not sure but I think I got his problem: He want to filter the red rows because the value before each red row (with same `name` and `client_id`) is the same.

Comment: Yes finally got it thanks to your answer below, your solution works well, vote up !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution using `LAG`:

```
SELECT t.id, t.client_id, t.name, t.value, t.`date`
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, name ORDER BY ID) AS lastValue
  FROM tableA
) t WHERE t.value <> t.lastValue OR t.lastValue IS NULL
ORDER BY ID
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffe5fc5748326362e68187469ece0708)